# Logout button does not appear after user logs in

Tags: php, html

After users log in, they should be able to see logout but the problem is they can only see login button. Logout button is missing. I am using slide down panel. I know I'm missing some conditional clause(?) in my html but I just know how and where to write it. Please help me.

html/index.php

```
    <div id="toppanel">
    <div id="panel">
        <div class="content clearfix">
            <div class="left">
                <!-- Login Form -->
                <form class="clearfix" action="validate2.php" method="post">
                    <h1>Member Login</h1>
                    <label class="grey" for="log">Email:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="email" id="log" value="" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="pwd">Password:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="password" name="password" id="pwd" size="23" placeholder="********" />
                    <label><input name="rememberme" id="rememberme" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="forever" /> &nbsp;Remember me</label>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="bt_login" />
                    <a class="lost-pwd" href="#">Lost your password?</a>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="left">          
                <!-- Register Form -->
                <form action="#" method="post">
                    <h1>Not a member yet? Sign Up!</h1>             
                    <label class="grey" for="email">Email:</label>
                        <input class="field" type="text" name="email" id="signup" value="" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="password">Password:</label>
                        <input class="field" type="text" name="password" id="email" size="23" placeholder="********" />
                    <label class="grey" for="email">Confirm Password:</label>
                        <input class="field" type="text" name="password" id="email" size="23" placeholder="********" />
            </div>
            <div class="left right">
                    <label class="grey" for="email">Contact No</label>
                        <input class="field" type="text" name="email" id="signup" value="" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="email">Campus</label>
                    <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="campus" /><?php if (isset($campus) && $campus=="Jerudong")?><value="Jerudong">Jerudong
                        <input type="radio" name="campus" /><?php if (isset($campus) && $campus=="Gadong") ?><value="Gadong">Gadong
                    <label class="grey" for="email">Class</label>
                        <input class="field" type="text" name="email" id="signup" value="" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="email">Intake</label>
                        <input class="field" type="text" name="email" id="signup" value="" size="23" />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" class="bt_register" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /login -->
    </div>
    <!-- The tab on top --> 
    <div class="tab">
        <ul class="login">
            <li class="left">&nbsp;</li>
            <li>Hello!</li>
            <li class="sep">|</li>
            <li id="toggle">
                <a id="open" class="open" href="#">Log In | Register</a>
                <a id="close" style="display: none;" class="close" href="#">Close Panel</a>         
            </li>
            <li class="right">&nbsp;</li>
        </ul> 
    </div> <!-- / top -->

<!-- The tab on top -->
    <div class="tab">
        <ul class="login">
            <li class="left"> </li>
            <!-- Logout -->
            <li>Hello, <?php echo $_SESSION['email'] ?></li>
            <li><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
            <li class="sep">|</li>

            <li id="toggle">
            <a id="open" class="open" href="#" rel="nofollow">Show Dashboard</a>
            <a id="close" style="display: none;" class="close" href="#" rel="nofollow">Close Panel</a>
            </li>
            <li class="right"> </li>
        </ul>
    </div> <!-- / top -->
```

validate2.php

```
<?php 

include 'connection.php';
if (isset($_POST["login"])){
//get data from login form
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);

//select all data by using email and password entered
$customers = mysql_query("select * from customer where CustomerEmail='".$email."' and CustomerPassword='".$password."'");
$customer = mysql_num_rows($customers);

$managers = mysql_query("select * from manager where ManagerEmail='".$email."' and ManagerPassword='".$password."'");
$manager = mysql_num_rows($managers);

$staffs = mysql_query("select * from staff where StaffEmail='".$email."' and StaffPassword='".$password."'");
$staff = mysql_num_rows($staffs);

    //if customer is true
    if($customer== 1){
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($customers);
        $id= $row['CustomerID'];
        $email = $row['CustomerEmail'];
        $name = $row['CustomerName'];

        //start session
        session_start();
        //create session
        $_SESSION['CustomerID'] = $id;
        $_SESSION['CustomerEmail'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['CustomerName'] = $name;

        //redirect page to index.php    
        header("Location: index.php");
        }

    //if manager is true
    else if($manager == 1){
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($managers);
        $id = $row['ManagerID'];
        $email = $row['ManagerEmail'];
        $name = $row['ManagerName'];

        //start session
        session_start();
        //create session
        $id = $row['ManagerID'] = $id;
        $_SESSION['ManagerEmail'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['ManagerName'] = $name;

        //redirect page to managerCP.php
        header("Location: managercp.php");
        }

    //if staff is true
    else if($staff == 1){
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($staff);
        $id = $row['StaffID'];
        $email = $row['StaffEmail'];
        $name = $row['StaffName'];

        //start session
        session_start();
        //create session
        $id = $row['StaffID'] = $id;
        $_SESSION['StaffEmail'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['StaffName'] = $name;

        //redirect page to staffCP.php
        header("Location: staffcp.php");
        }

    //if all condition is false 
    else    {
//alert will be appeared
header("Location: index.php?login=Wrong email or password");    
}
}
?>


</div>
```

So I edited and I got an error that says unexpected 'else'.

```
    <li class="left"> </li>
    <?php if(isset($_GET['login'])) {?>
    <!-- Logout -->
    <li>Hello, <?php echo $_SESSION['email'] ?></li>
    <li><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
    <li class="sep">|</li>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php else { ?>
    <div class="content clearfix">
            <div class="left">
                <!-- Login Form -->
                <form class="clearfix" action="validate2.php" method="post">
                    <h1>Member Login</h1>
                    <label class="grey" for="log">Email:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="email" id="log" value="" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="pwd">Password:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="password" name="password" id="pwd" size="23" placeholder="********" />
                    <label><input name="rememberme" id="rememberme" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="forever" /> &nbsp;Remember me</label>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="bt_login" />
                    <a class="lost-pwd" href="#">Lost your password?</a>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="left">          
                <!-- Register Form -->
                <form action="#" method="post">
                    <h1>Not a member yet? Sign Up!</h1>             
                    <label class="grey" for="email">Email:</label>
                        <input class="field" type="text" name="email" id="signup" value="" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="password">Password:</label>
                        <input class="field" type="text" name="password" id="email" size="23" placeholder="********" />
                    <label class="grey" for="email">Confirm Password:</label>
                        <input class="field" type="text" name="password" id="email" size="23" placeholder="********" />
            </div>
            <div class="left right">
                    <label class="grey" for="email">Contact No</label>
                        <input class="field" type="text" name="email" id="signup" value="" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="email">Campus</label>
                    <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="campus" /><?php if (isset($campus) && $campus=="Jerudong")?><value="Jerudong">Jerudong
                        <input type="radio" name="campus" /><?php if (isset($campus) && $campus=="Gadong") ?><value="Gadong">Gadong
                    <label class="grey" for="email">Class</label>
                        <input class="field" type="text" name="email" id="signup" value="" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="email">Intake</label>
                        <input class="field" type="text" name="email" id="signup" value="" size="23" />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" class="bt_register" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /login -->
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: session_start() should be called once at the start of every script, before any output. Call it once in your validate script. Did you call It on the index.php? If not, it will not be populated.

Comment: Yes i already called it on the index page. @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: The HTML here has no conditional logic so the logout link should always display. Do you have any script hiding it?

Comment: I don't think I have any script hiding it. I thought we have to use if, else, etc. no? @MichaelBerkowski

Answer (score 0):

### Solution and Critique

I don't quite understand why all of the login, registration, and logout information is on the same page however if you want it this way you'll have to add PHP conditionals managing what gets shown when certain session material is set.

I would assume that the conditional you are talking about because the logout stuff is not showing would be around this area:

```
<li class="left"> </li>
<?php if $_SESSION['logged_in'] {?>
    <!-- Logout -->
    <li>Hello, <?php echo $_SESSION['email'] ?></li>
    <li><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
    <li class="sep">|</li>
...<?php } ?>
<?php else { ?>
    <!--Things to show when user is not logged in-->
<?php } ?>
```

### Please use PDO

It is highly recommended that you use PDO (PHP Data Objects) when initiating a connection with database to ensure security and protect against [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). This is really an essential part of any secure PHP application as far as using a database goes and it has great support for database types and is very easy to [learn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QtCdk459NFg)

Comment: Its not essential to use PDO, MySQLi also provides prepared statements which can deal with SQL injection attacks. http://indieteq.com/index/readmore/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php Its really just down to preference for most people.

Comment: "This is really an essential part of any secure PHP application as far as using a database goes and it has great support for database types and is very easy to learn"... I do agree with you though that preventing SQL injection is essential.

Comment: Have you added php conditionals to the page?

Comment: No I have not. Please help me @DomFarolino

Comment: Just add some php conditionals like in the above answer around each separate "view module" if you will. Model each conditional statement based off of perhaps session information that may exist if the user is logged in but may not exist of no user is logged in. Does this make sense?